# How to compare two timestamps - differing only because one has a timezone?

Tags: date, datetime, go, testify

I'm trying to test that the `time.Time` value I inserted into a postgres database is the same one I am querying out. Postgres drops the timezone though, so I'm wondering how can I get this testify/assert test to pass?

`s.Equal(want.Date, got.Date)`

Both are the dame datatype `time.Time` but the first has the timezone:

`2020-10-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`

I created this value like this - `time.Date()` must take a location, so I couldn't create it without one by passing nil:

`want.Date := time.Date(2020, 10, 31, 00, 00, 00, 0000, time.UTC)`

`got.Date` coming from the database looks like:

`2020-10-31 00:00:00 +0000 +0000`

I can't change the database dropping the timezone, so how can I change how I create the date or how can I drop the timezone? Or perhaps there is another way I can assert that the year, month, and day, are the same?

Answer (score 3):

Use `time.Time.Equal` to test if two values of `time.Time` type are equal or not.

```
$ go doc time.Time.Equal
package time // import "time"

func (t Time) Equal(u Time) bool
    Equal reports whether t and u represent the same time instant. Two times can
    be equal even if they are in different locations. For example, 6:00 +0200
    and 4:00 UTC are Equal. See the documentation on the Time type for the
    pitfalls of using == with Time values; most code should use Equal instead.
```

Comment: Ah, I was trying the approach of removing the timezone from one, which I couldn't find how to do and keep it a time.Time value still. Thanks!